# Splash screen Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, splash-screen

I am facing strange issue in Splash screen of windows phone 8.1 store app.

Scale   Image size (pixels)
1x   - 480 x 800
1.4x - 672 x 1120
2.4x - 152 x 1920

Thses standard sizes I have given. Although Image does not look proper in 4.7 inch 720P devices.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I usually provide only 2.4x scale splash screen (1152 x 1920) and it works correctly for all resolutions.

Comment: does not works at my end. image is not displayed full screen in this case. can you elaborate more?

Comment: Do you use an image in Visual Assets in Package.appxmanifest as your splash screen or you have ExtendedSplashScreen as a separate Page?

Comment: I am using image. all 3 images are of required sizes

Comment: means splash screen cuts little bit from top and bottom in 720P

Comment: It's because 720p has different aspect ratio than images in Visual Assets. You probably need to use an ExtendedSplashScreen and create your own layout (e.g. with image that won't crop). More information here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh868191.aspx

Comment: I have read about ExtendedSplashScreen. but wanted to check if I can do it with just images.

Answer (score 5):

I don't think theres much you can do to improve this (except like @neoproudek suggested using `ExtendedSplashScreen`s)

But depending on your senario, you may only have to change the `Splash Screen Background Color` to a color that accommodates the Splash screen image color. Thus if you have a single color background splash screen image, such as the [Windows Phone Music app](https://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/music/d2b6a184-da39-4c9a-9e0a-8b589b03dec0) with an **Empty** `Splash Screen Background Color` it will look like this:

[image: Blank background color]

But changing the `Splash Screen Background Color` to **#107C0F** like so:

[image: Splash Screen Background Color]

*Quick note: Splash Screen Background Color does not have an alpha component*

The end result is a good looking Splash screen:

[image: Appropriate background color]

Hope this helps!

Comment: I have not done this because my splash has gradient background :P

Comment: @vITs Conundrum yes.. :P, if you do not wish to go the `ExtendedSplashScreen` way I would suggest playing around with colors until you find some color for the background that looks accommodating, other than that I'm not sure. Good luck!

Comment: yes that will be last option indeed. anyways thanks for answer! +1

Answer (score 2):

You can (only) do it with just images (through appxmanifest) if you prepare the splash screen so, that the top and bottom parts are in uniform colored fill, which you can seamlessly extend to the top and bottom of the screen by setting the Splash Screen Background color in Package.appxmanifest.

Comment: have you seen how it looks on 720P? no matter how our image is, its cuts from top and bottom just because of required aspect ratio is not provided.

Comment: Right. I thought it was funny when you said cut - I understood that as cropped, sorry. So the image has black pillars on top and bottom, as the screen is of a higher ratio - I edited my answer, but the answer above by @Barnstokkr explains it very well and with screenshots - I think you should accept that one. ;)